# Percentage to total in BigQuery Legacy SQL (Subqueries?)

Tags: google-bigquery

I can't understand how to calulate percentage to total in BigQuery Legacy SQL.
So, I have a table:

```
ID | Name  | Group | Mark
1  | John  |  A    |  10
2  | Lucy  |  A    |  5
3  | Jane  |  A    |  7
4  | Lily  |  B    |  9
5  | Steve |  B    |  14
6  | Rita  |  B    |  11
```

I want to calculate percentage like this:

```
ID | Name  | Group | Mark | Percent
1  | John  |  A    |  10  | 10/(10+5+7)=45%
2  | Lucy  |  A    |  5   | 5/(10+5+7)=22%
3  | Jane  |  A    |  7   | 7/(10+5+7)=33%
4  | Lily  |  B    |  9   | 9/(9+14+11)=26%
5  | Steve |  B    |  14  | 14/(9+14+11)=42%
6  | Rita  |  B    |  11  | 11/(9+14+11)=32%
```

My table is quite long for me (3 million rows).
I thought that I could do it with subqueries, but in SELECT I can't use subqueries.
Does anyone know a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  ID, Name, [Group], Mark, 
  RATIO_TO_REPORT(Mark) OVER(PARTITION BY [Group]) AS percent 
FROM YourTable
```

Check more about [RATIO_TO_REPORT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#syntax-window-functions)